# How to use unique_ptr to access class members and class variables in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a header file where I have defined a class and also used a unique_ptr to access the class members.
But I don't know how to access it from clone.cpp
Generally, what we do is create an object of the class
For example:

```
A obj;
bool res = obj.concate("hello");
```

How can we do it using unique_ptr?

When I am trying to do

```
bool result = access->concate("hello");
```

I am getting the following error:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>  "obja()", referenced from:
>      _main in classA.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> ```

```
clone.h
--------

std::unique_ptr<class A> obja();

class A
{
public:
  bool concate(string str){
  string a = "hello";
  return a == str;
  }
private:
   string b = "world";
};


clone.cpp
________

int main(){
 auto access = obja();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same way as you dereference raw pointers, using the `->` operator.

Comment: Oh boy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. You have declared a function named `obja`, and you are calling it - but you haven't actually implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need *class* in `std::unique_ptr<class A> obja();`, same about brackets.

Not sure what r you trying to achieve here: `auto access = obja();`
I assume you tried to call concate there, then everything can be like this:

```
class A
{
public:
   bool concate(string str) {
      string a = "hello";
      return a == str;
   }
private:
   string b = "world";
};

std::unique_ptr<A> obja;

int main() {
   auto access = obja->concate("test");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class A
 { 
       public:
         bool concate(string str) { string a = "hello"; return a == str; } 

       private: string b = "world"; 
};

std::unique_ptr<A> obja = std::make_unique <A>; 

int main() { 
   auto access = obja->concate("test"); return 0;
 }
```

You just forget allocate memory. :)